# Scala can not convert expression of Double to Int

Tags: scala, casting, type-conversion

I have the following method, which returns the absolute value of the distance between two points as an `Int`.

```
  def absDist(a: Tuple2[Int, Int], b: Tuple2[Int, Int]): Int = {
    ((scala.math.pow(a._1 - b._1, 2) + scala.math.pow(a._2 - b._2, 2)): Int)
  }
```

However, the type can not be converted:

```
Expression of type Double doesn't conform to expected type Int
```

Why is this happening? My conversion looks good to me.

Comment: Probably you already know this and you got it covered but converting a double to an integer will result in precision loss.

Comment: You cannot convert an expression of type `Double` to `Int` by putting `: Int` after it. Doing that is the same as trying to assign the `Double` value to a variable of type `Int` - it's not going to convert it automatically, and you'll get an error from the compiler. Specifying the type explicitly is not the same as converting to that type. Use `toInt` instead.

Answer (score 5):

Use `toInt` to do type conversion:

```
def absDist(a: Tuple2[Int, Int], b: Tuple2[Int, Int]): Int = {
    (scala.math.pow(a._1 - b._1, 2) + scala.math.pow(a._2 - b._2, 2)).toInt
}
```